# Error 080070020 on Update to Windows 10 Preview

Tags: nokia-lumia-920, insider-preview, windows-10-mobile

I have a Lumia 920 and signed in to the insider program. I installed the Windows Preview App, selected "Slow Ring", headed to "update" and saw that I have an update available. I clicked 'download' and after this finished, I clicked 'install'.

Then the phone restarted, I saw the gears, and after 3 minutes or so, it restartet again, and bootet to the normal WP8.1 screen, having an open message box saying "Could not install update. Error code 080070020".

I already googled and set the date time to manual. I also have 11GB free disk space. I already tried the install about 5 times, to no avail...

I have no idea what to do. Any help appreciated.

Comment: 0x80070020 is normally "file in use" - have you retried at all?

Comment: I have retried about 20 times now... I even switched to fast ring and tried several times...

Comment: Do you have sd card in your phone?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only solution for me was, to do a hardreset.

Answer (score 0):

You can check the region of your phone. Is it correct or not.
And in addition to that, check the language you have selected. The regional language and phone language must be same.